# Calling non-async methods inside async function

Tags: c#, async-await

Please help me understand the async/await operation for the below piece of code.

```
1. public async Task OuterMethodAsync(MyObject obj1)

2. {

3.     var dbResult = await repo.SomeDB_GetCallAsync(obj1.id);

4.     var httpResult = await Function1ContainingHTTPCallAsync(dbResult);

5.     dbResult.param1 = obj1.param1;

6.     var isSuccess = Function2(httpResult, dbResult);

7.     await repo.SomeDB_UpdateAsync(dbResult);

8.     if(isSuccess)
9.      {
10.         // Do some stuff
11.     }

12. }
```

The *Function2* is supposed to return false, if its input parameter *httpResult* is null.

Based on the logs in the *Function1ContainingHTTPCallAsync*,

1. It has successfully executed the http call,
2. Returned a valid response *httpResult* which is a non-empty string

However, based on the logs in the *Function2*,

1. It has received the input parameter *httpResult* as null
2. Returned a false

Here,

1. The *Function2* is **not async**
2. *Function1ContainingHTTPCallAsync* is **async**
3. *SomeDB_GetCallAsync* is **async**
4. *SomeDB_UpdateAsync* is **async**
5. *OuterMethodAsync* is **async**

The problem I am seeing here is that the isSuccess is being set to false. Also, note that there is a possibility of the OuterMethod being called more than once (thats a retry mechanism in the framework for a failed HTTP call). Considering the fact that the OuterMethod is by itself an API being called as a HTTP call, would it cause this issue?

Comment: This does not compile, because `OuterMethod` has no return type. Please show your real code.

Comment: A parameter of Line 6 is the result of Line 4, so Line 6 cannot be executed before Line 4.

Comment: @SomeBody OuterMethod returns void (Task)

Comment: Also anything that is `async` should be suffixed with `Async`. However my OCD aside. `await` actually awaits, although some of this code will likely get pushed off to *IO completion ports*, the code will run in sequence. The answer is, no, assuming you `await` all your *async* calls, line 6 will not be executed before line 4

Comment: Is it possible your assumption (which can happen only when the line 6 gets executed before line 4) is flawed? If that assumption would be correct, `Function2` would be utterly useless unless you depend on some side effects of it. Anyway, what stops you from debugging this and stepping through it to see what happens?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @oerkelens
Based on the logs in the *Function1ContainingHTTPCallAsync*, 
1. It has successfully executed the http call, 
2. Returned a valid response *httpResult* which is a non-empty string

However, based on the logs in the *Function2*, 
1. It has received the input parameter *httpResult* as null 
2. Returned a false

Answer (score 2):

> The problem I am seeing here is that the isSuccess is being set to false, which can happen only when the line 6 gets executed before line 4.

You have the correct `await` usage, so: line 6 **is not** executing before it should be. You're going to have to look into what scenarios `Function2` can return `false`, and perhaps *use a debugger* to see what is happening. The code as shown is fine in as much as we can tell from here.

Note that in a debugging environment, you might be able to see the value of `isSuccess` *before it is meaningfully defined/assigned* - for example, if you put a break-point on `OuterMethod`. That doesn't mean line 6 has executed; it just means that debuggers see behind the curtain. Strictly speaking, the value is undefined before line 6, but in reality since the C# compiler emits `.locals init` (at least currently), it will be `false`, since `false` is the default value of `bool`.

You might also want to check whether `OuterMethod` might be being called twice independently.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I have added a few more points:

The *Function2* is supposed to return false, only if its input parameter *httpResult* is null. 

Based on the logs in the *Function1ContainingHTTPCallAsync*, it has been successfully executed, and returned a valid response *httpResult* which is a non-empty string

However, based on the logs in the *Function2*, it has received the input parameter *httpResult* as null and thereby, returned a false

Comment: @CodingEveryDay then you need to look at `Function1ContainingHTTPCallAsync` to see in what scenarios it can return `null` - perhaps there is a rogue `catch (Exception ex) { Log(ex); return null; }` - because the code as written: is fine. Or, and I repeat myself: **use the debugger**, and *see* what the values are

Comment: This has occured in production setup, where I see the logs, When I try it locally with debug points, its not the same. The Function2 is in fact returning a true

Comment: @CodingEveryDay then you need to improve the logging; whatever is happening: it isn't specific to the code you've shown, so you need to look beyond that

Comment: I agree. Also, there is a possibility of the OuterMethod being called more than once (thats a retry mechanism in the framework for a failed HTTP call). The OuterMethod 
 is by itself an API being called as a HTTP call. Would this cause this issue?

Comment: @CodingEveryDay to comment on that I'd need enough code to basically repro it; you have the code, I don't; you'll have to investigate that